# How to make database object to use with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

MSDN expalins it as belows

```
// Northwnd inherits from System.Data.Linq.DataContext.
Northwnd nw = new Northwnd(@"northwnd.mdf");
// or, if you are not using SQL Server Express
// Northwnd nw = new Northwnd("Database=Northwind;Server=server_name;Integrated Security=SSPI");

var companyNameQuery =
    from cust in nw.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust.CompanyName;

foreach (var customer in companyNameQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(customer);
}
```

Here My database name is Madu and the table is Student with Name,Course and Address. My coding is below

```
Madu md = new Madu("Database=Madu;Server=Madu-DV6080;Integrated Security=SSPI");

var courseQuery =from stu in md.Student where stu.Address == "London" select stu.Name;

foreach (var stu in courseQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stu);
}
```

I have added "System.Data.Linq" reference as well.But it gives me an error "The type or namespace name 'Madu' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Please help me. Thanx in advance..!

Comment: Can you show us the definition of class Madu? What namespace is it in? What assembly?

Comment: have you generated your model, what is it called? Use EF and reasearch database first approaches, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the code you posted:

```
// Northwnd inherits from System.Data.Linq.DataContext.
```

So you'll need this as the bare minimum:

```
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Mabu : DataContext
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

where "Stuff" involves setting up your context to match the database you're working with.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb386940%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) explains how to set up your context.